# using 2 order parameters on firebase query, but result is not ordered by any of them

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following query

```
admin.firestore()
    .collection("articles")
    .orderBy("publishDate", "desc")
    .where("publishDate", ">=", mintime)
    .orderBy("views", "desc")
    .limit(10);
```

The query gives the top 10 articles within a week ordered by their views I get no errors, but the resulting articles are not necessarily the articles with the highest view count. Small remark the 10 articles that are return are not sorted either, to fix this I just sorted the 10 articles after I got them from firebase, but it makes me think I'm doing something wrong. So is there anyway to fix this query to relably get the top articles within a date and ordered by views?

EDIT

I will try to explain it a little differently this query:

```
admin.firestore()
    .collection("articles")
    .orderBy("publishDate", "desc")
    .where("publishDate", ">=", mintime)
    .orderBy("views", "desc")
    .limit(10);
```

And this query

```
admin.firestore()
    .collection("articles")
    .orderBy("publishDate", "desc")
    .where("publishDate", ">=", mintime)
    .limit(10);
```

returns the same result, it is like the `.orderBy("views", "desc")` gets ignored, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> the 10 articles that are return are not sorted either, to fix this I just sorted the 10 articles after I got them from firebase

This is exactly what you have to do, and there are no workarounds for making Firestore do this for you, given the query you have now.

A secondary orderBy doesn't reorder the entire set of results again.  It just sorts the documents within the values clustered by the primary sort value.  This behavior is covered by an example in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data).  Look for part where it says "You can also order by multiple fields".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it helped, but there is still something I cannot get to work, I edited the post, hope it clarifies :)

Comment: If you have a second question, you should post it separately.  Stack Overflow only allows one question per post.  Please edit the question to remove the additions and post separately.

Comment: This was the original question it just added the part of it not sorting the resulting 10 articles because it might help you to find the error, sorry if the question is unclear.

Comment: The answer is still the same, regardless.  Secondary sorts don't reorder the entire set of results, as I explained in my answer, and is explained in the documentation I linked to.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but if I have 11 articles and the 11'th article has the most views that article is still not included with the query above. So it is true that the articles are not sorted as you have explained, but why is the 11'th article not included in the 10 that are returned. This is an example that I just tested and that I don't understand this behavior.

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't possible with Firestore.  You can't get ordering on a different field than the one you use in a range filter.  Please read that documentation I linked to.